# Force CETAS to only write one file?

Tags: azure-synapse

If I run a CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT * FROM DistributedTable, then I end up with 60 files in blob storage. If I do CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT * from sys.objects, I get one file in blob storage. That's as I would expect.

How can I get the first CETAS from the distributed table to write to only one file? Once replicated tables are supported in Azure SQL DW, does a CETAS from a replicated table guarantee to only create one file?

The scenario is wanting to export one file per day to blob storage. Apparently the consuming application expects just one file and the rowcount is small enough that if it did export to 60 files, most would be blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sys.objects table is stored on the Control Node of the SQL Data Warehouse (instead of being distributed over the compute nodes). So CETAS on this table is performed by 1 writer thread which creates 1 file in blob storage. The data in a distributed table is sharded across 60 distributions, thus a CETAS on a distributed table in SQL DW will always create 60 files, 1 file is written per distribution in parallel.

One workaround to force a single file to be written for a distributed table is to use the TOP clause in the SELECT portion of the statement.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.Finance --N rows

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dbo.FinanceExternal
WITH (  LOCATION = '/finance/', DATA_SOURCE = AzureStorage, FILE_FORMAT = TextFile)
AS SELECT TOP N * FROM dbo.FinanceNew;
```

Since the TOP expression is evaluated on the Control Node, the rows of your distributed table will be moved to the Control Node. Subsequently, 1 writer thread would write the result set to a single file in blob storage.

And yes, in the future when replicated tables are supported in SQL DW, the CETAS of a replicated table will create only one file.

Sahaj

To understand the SQL DW architecture and role of control/compute nodes, refer to: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-overview-what-is/